# Quelle est le mot correct ? chercheur ou bien demandeur?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Quelle est la phrase correcte ?

> Le client peut être chercheur d'emploi et chercheur de services.

ou bien :

> Le client peut être demandeur d'emploi et demandeur de services.

Answer (score 1):

***Demandeur d'emploi*** est de loin le plus courant mais on utilise aussi parfois *chercheur d'emploi*.

***Demandeur de service*** est possible et je n'ai jamais entendu *chercheur de service*, ce serait plutôt : *à la recherche de services*.